# JsonMappingException can not deserialize instance out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, api, jackson, fasterxml, coinbase-api

I've looked at other answers and still can't identify my issue.

I'm using an unfinished Coinbase API v2 library and am having some issues.

The method is calling mapper.treeToValue(dataNode, classz);

Where the dataNode is a JSONNode with the following JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": "xxxx",
        "name": "LTC Wallet",
        "primary": false,
        "type": "wallet",
        "currency": {
            "code": "LTC",
            "name": "Litecoin",
            "color": "#B5B5B5",
            "exponent": 8,
            "type": "crypto",
            "address_regex": "^(L|M|3)[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"
        },
        "balance": {
            "amount": "xxx",
            "currency": "LTC"
        },
        "created_at": "xxx",
        "updated_at": "xxx",
        "resource": "account",
        "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/xxx"
    },
    {
        "id": "xxx",
        "name": "ETH Wallet",
        "primary": false,
        "type": "wallet",
        "currency": {
            "code": "ETH",
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "color": "#6F7CBA",
            "exponent": 8,
            "type": "crypto",
            "address_regex": "^(?:0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$"
        },
        "balance": {
            "amount": "xxx",
            "currency": "ETH"
        },
        "created_at": "xxx",
        "updated_at": "xxx",
        "resource": "account",
        "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/xxx"
    }
]
```

classz is of Class type where T is the following class;

```
public class ListAccount extends ListResponse<Account> {
```

And ListResponse is the following;

```
public abstract class ListResponse<T> {

    private Pagination pagination;
    private List<T> data;

    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return pagination;
    }
    public void setPagination(Pagination pagination) {
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }
    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've solved this by removing the ListResponse class and parsing the value as List<Account>. It is not a cleaner solution, but it functions.

Comment: For anyone in the future with this issue; I'm not sure of the exact reason this wasn't working correctly, but my changes ensured the parser parsed the objects correctly and returned a List<T> instead of the response object.